# Clear the "new mail envelope" from outlook taskbar in VSTO

Tags: vb.net, vsto, outlook-addin

I've got an add-in that processes and then moves certain incoming emails. The only unfortunate consequence of this is that the "new mail envelope" on the taskbar:

[image: Screenshot of the new mail icon]

remains lit when there isn't any mail for the user to look at.

There's a  VBA solution to this issue here: http://www.outlookcode.com/d/code/clearenvicon.htm

It doesn't seem easily portable to VB though - after clearing up what were to me the obvious changes suggested I end up with:

```
Module RemoveNotification
' Code sample by Outlook MVP "Neo"
' Removes the New Mail icon from the Windows system tray,
' and resets Outlook's new mail notification engine.
' Tested against Outlook 2000 (IMO) and Outlook 2002 (POP Account)
' Send questions and comments to neo@mvps.org
' WARNING: Due to the use of AddressOf, code must
' go into a module and not ThisOutlookSession or
' a class module
' Entry Point is RemoveNewMailIcon.

Public Const WUM_RESETNOTIFICATION As Long = &H407

'Required Public constants, types & declares
'for the Shell_Notify API method
Public Const NIM_ADD As Long = &H0
Public Const NIM_MODIFY As Long = &H1
Public Const NIM_DELETE As Long = &H2

Public Const NIF_ICON As Long = &H2 'adding an ICON
Public Const NIF_TIP As Long = &H4 'adding a TIP
Public Const NIF_MESSAGE As Long = &H1 'want return messages

' Structure needed for Shell_Notify API
Structure NOTIFYICONDATA
    Dim cbSize As Long
    Dim hwnd As Long
    Dim uID As Long
    Dim uFlags As Long
    Dim uCallbackMessage As Long
    Dim hIcon As Long
    Dim szTip As String * 64
End Structure

Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
  (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long,
ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Any) As Long

Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" _
  Alias "GetClassNameA" _
  (ByVal hwnd As Long,
  ByVal lpClassName As String,
  ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long

Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" _
  Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" _
  (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" _
  Alias "GetWindowTextA" _
  (ByVal hwnd As Long,
  ByVal lpString As String,
  ByVal cch As Long) As Long

Declare Function EnumWindows Lib "user32" _
  (ByVal lpEnumFunc As Long,
  ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Declare Function Shell_NotifyIcon Lib "shell32.dll" _
  Alias "Shell_NotifyIconA" _
  (ByVal dwMessage As Long,
  lpData As NOTIFYICONDATA) As Long

Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
  (ByVal lpClassName As String,
  ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

' This is the entry point that makes it happen
Sub RemoveNewMailIcon()
    EnumWindows AddressOf EnumWindowProc, 0
End Sub

Public Function EnumWindowProc(ByVal hwnd As Long,
  ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

    'Do stuff here with hwnd
    Dim sClass As String
    Dim sIDType As String
    Dim sTitle As String
    Dim hResult As Long

    sTitle = GetWindowIdentification(hwnd, sIDType, sClass)
    If sTitle = "rctrl_renwnd32" Then
        hResult = KillNewMailIcon(hwnd)
    End If

    If hResult Then
        EnumWindowProc = False
        ' Reset the new mail notification engine
        Call SendMessage(hwnd, WUM_RESETNOTIFICATION, 0&, 0&)
    Else
        EnumWindowProc = True
    End If
End Function

Private Function GetWindowIdentification(ByVal hwnd As Long,
  sIDType As String,
  sClass As String) As String

    Dim nSize As Long
    Dim sTitle As String

    'get the size of the string required
    'to hold the window title
    nSize = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd)
    'if the return is 0, there is no title
    If nSize > 0 Then
        sTitle = Space$(nSize + 1)
        Call GetWindowText(hwnd, sTitle, nSize + 1)
        sIDType = "title"
        sClass = Space$(64)
        Call GetClassName(hwnd, sClass, 64)
    Else
        'no title, so get the class name instead
        sTitle = Space$(64)
        Call GetClassName(hwnd, sTitle, 64)
        sClass = sTitle
        sIDType = "class"
    End If

    GetWindowIdentification = TrimNull(sTitle)
End Function

Private Function TrimNull(startstr As String) As String
    Dim pos As Integer
    pos = InStr(startstr, Chr$(0))
    If pos Then
        TrimNull = Left(startstr, pos - 1)
        Exit Function
    End If

    'if this far, there was
    'no Chr$(0), so return the string
    TrimNull = startstr
End Function

Private Function KillNewMailIcon(ByVal hwnd As Long) As Boolean
    Dim pShell_Notify As NOTIFYICONDATA
    Dim hResult As Long

    'setup the Shell_Notify structure
    pShell_Notify.cbSize = Len(pShell_Notify)
    pShell_Notify.hwnd = hwnd
    pShell_Notify.uID = 0

    ' Remove it from the system tray and catch result
    hResult = Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, pShell_Notify)
    If (hResult) Then
        KillNewMailIcon = True
    Else
        KillNewMailIcon = False
    End If
End Function
End Module
```

Which gives the below errors & warnings:

```
Severity    Code    Description Line
Error   BC30205 End of statement expected.  35
Error   BC30800 Method arguments must be enclosed in parentheses.   73
Error   BC30828 'As Any' is not supported in 'Declare' statements.  40
Error   BC30581 'AddressOf' expression cannot be converted to 'Long' because 'Long' is not a delegate type. 73
Error   BC30277 Type character '$' does not match declared data type 'Char'.    129
Warning BC42104 Variable 'sIDType' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime. 85
Warning BC42104 Variable 'sClass' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.  85
Warning BC42109 Variable 'pShell_Notify' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime. Make sure the structure or all the reference members are initialized before use   145
```

Comment: Which part doesn't seem portable? Looks straightforward enough

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of clarity, while some of the differences between VBA and VB were easy for me to solve, others had no solution which was obvious to me. I also felt that there would be a "better" way of doing it in VB as it was a more feature-rich language with deeper ties to the underlying application.

Comment: Part of the conversion would need to be converting to vb.net types. Some of the pinvoke calls aren't correct in vb.net. For example the `Long` in `Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Any) As Long` should be `Integer` in vb.net: `Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Integer, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As String) As Long`. The `Any` should be `String`. See https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendmessage

Comment: OK - I can see that there's a list of other functions on the left of your link, that I can presumably then check against the other `Declare` statements in the code and it looks like I pick the signature closest to the one in the linked code and paste it into my code. Further on though I get the error message `'AddressOf' expression cannot be converted to 'Long' because 'Long' is not a delegate type.` How do I resolve this?